# Search Results In Dropdown Below Textbox Like Google (ASP)

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net

When someone starts typing in the search-textbox, there must popup a ''dropbox'' below the textbox with the found items. Like Google.

I need this for an ASP.NET (aspx) site, can anyone suggest me something like this?

I really don't know where to begin with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery Autocomplete: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

You'll need to know how to set up/work with a web service, but after that it's pretty darned simple.